# Virtual Environment Setup Fails on CentOS7 With Python3.6

Tags: python-3.6, centos7, python-venv

Following these directions:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7

The following command:

```
  $ python3.6 -m venv my_env
```

Will give the error:

```
Error: Command '['/home/username/mudlan-master/environments/my_env/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to update your virtualenv using pip3?

Comment: Yes, I used the following to install pip3: sudo yum -y install python36u-pip

Answer (score 1):

I had pip3 installed locally outside of the package manager. I removed it from /usr/local/bin/pip3*, and reinstalled:

```
  $ sudo yum remove python36u-pip
  $ sudo yum install python36u-pip
```

Comment: It's good to hear you solved it. And it could also be solved with `sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv`.